# Как получить день недели, предварительно сделав смещение на N часов?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Возникла у меня такая задача: вычислить и вывести в переменную день недели, предварительно прибавив к дате, из которой высчитывается день недели, N часов.
В моем случае N = 2. Иными словами, день недели на сайте должен изменяться не в 00:00 а в 02:00 ночи.  
Я по многочисленным советам на форумах наворотить смог только вот такую дьявольскую конструкцию:

```
$mydate=date('H:i:s'); //получаем текущее время
$mydate = new DateTime($mydate); //преобразуем
$mydate->modify("+2 hour"); //прибавляем 2 часа
$mydate->format('H:i:s'); //опять преобразуем

$mydate = date("w",$mydate); //вычисляем день недели
echo $mydate; //публикуем на странице
```

Однако, как водится, работать она отказывается, а посему я пришел к вам за советом).
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data_now=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // текущее время   
$data2=date('l',strtotime("+2 hour",mktime(date('H'),date('i'),date('s'),date('m'),date('d'),date('Y')))); // +2 часа от текущей даты
```

так? )

Comment: Обратите внимание, "date('l',strtotime" - тут стоит строчная L.

Comment: Спасибо за короткое, ясное и грамотное решение)

Comment: @Stuf, сравните три вывода:

    fike@aves:~$ php -r "echo mktime(date('H'),date('i'),date('s'),date('m'),date('Y')).PHP_EOL;"
    1412242286
    fike@aves:~$ php -r "echo mktime().PHP_EOL;"
    1412242292
    fike@aves:~$ php -r "echo time().PHP_EOL;"
    1412242295

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify('+2 hour');
echo $date->format('l');
```

DateTime практически повторяет всякие `date_`-функции, просто в ООП-подходе.